# Automatic light change in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create a HTML program that changes the colours in the traffic light automatically in order when the user has clicked a button.

I have got the traffic light layout done and the colour to change when the user clicked one of three buttons.

Can anyone help me to make them light up automatically when the button is clicked?

It should light up red (wait 2 seconds), yellow (wait 2 seconds), Green and repeat.

I tried to research how to do this but I can't seem to find any solutions. All I found was how to make 1 colour change with 1 button.

```js
document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('clearLights').onclick = clearLights;
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = setTimeout(autoLights, 3000);

function stopRed() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function clearLights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function autoLights() {
  alert('Hello');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  height: 550px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bulb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
  <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
  <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
  <h1 id="clearLights" class="button">Clear</h1>
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: What's desired behaviour, exactly? Light up red, then yellow then green?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? where do you get stuck at? SO is not a "write code for me" service

Comment: HTML has little to do with this and it's all done with javascript. HTML is not a program or programming language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code you wrote and not to write code for you.

Comment: look into using setTimeout or setInterval to delay the changing of the lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i change your (autoLights) function

```js
        var counter = 2;
        var timerId = 0;

        document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
        document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
        document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
        document.getElementById('clearLights').onclick = clearLights;
        document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

        function stopRed() {
            document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

        function slowYellow() {
            document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        }

        function goGreen() {
            document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }


        function clearLights() {
            document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }

        function autoLights() {
            stopRed();
            timerId = setInterval(timer, 2000);
        }

        function timer() {
            if (counter == 1)
                stopRed();
            if (counter == 2)
                slowYellow();
            if (counter == 3)
                goGreen();
            counter++
            if (counter > 3)
                counter = 1;
        }
```

```css
body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        #controlPanel {
            float: left;
            padding-top: 30px;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: gray;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 90px 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #traffic-light {
            height: 550px;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #333;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: 30px 0;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .bulb {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: #111;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 25px auto;
            transition: background 500ms;
        }
```

```html
<div id="controlPanel">
        <h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
        <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
        <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
        <h1 id="clearLights" class="button">Clear</h1>
        <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="traffic-light">
        <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
        <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
        <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to do it with recursive function for counting. I want to help you, well, notice functions at the bottom, this should work (I see that you changed the question well I changed that timeout for 2 seconds as you wanted, I hope I helped you, let us here know if it is good enough for your question):

```js
document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('Lights').onclick = Lights;
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}    


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num){
 Lights();
    switch(num) {
        case 1:
            stopRed();
            break;
        case 2:
            slowYellow();
            break;
        case 3:
            goGreen();
            break;
        default:
            alert("you made some error");
      }  
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;
function timer() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    
    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if(counter == maxSec) {
         return;
     }
    timer();
    }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
    counter = 1;
    lightOne(counter);
    timer();
}
```

```css
  

    body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  height: 550px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bulb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}
```

```html
   <html>

<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
  <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
  <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
  <h1 id="Lights" class="button">Clear</h1>
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>   
</div>



</html>
```

Comment: no faults and errors... tested with firebug in firefox and with devtools in chrome ... you make a mistake while copying from here or some your other fault... here is pure code: https://codeshare.io/GLj6Dl